# How long do posts flagged as VLQ reside after my flag has been called "helpful"?

Tags: discussion

I was just wondering how long ***[this stinkeroonie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379047/when-was-the-term-web-site-or-website-first-used/454323#454323)*** was going to hang out...

[image]
It reads like some drunken rant, in which it appears he claims responsibility for coining the term "internet". My flag was marked as "helpful", and yet, there it is.

So, we could ask: What happens to VLQ flags? How long do they last? How many people need to flag as VLQ for the system to take action? And if a minor edit to a question or answer after being flagged renders the flag ineffective, how do we avoid this misuse of the system?

Comment: I rather think your flag was marked helpful because the post was subsequently edited (which must be an attempt to improve its quality, thus justifying your judgement). I've deleted the answer as a result of this Meta post. The question about longevity of flags remains, and I don't know the answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks. The sole reason for the Q was to prompt a little action on what I considered a poor example of what we do here. Should I delete the Q, or leave it for discussion...? BTW, I have another...

Comment: I think making the question of the title more prominent in the body might actually be useful. What happens to VLQ flags? How long do they last? How many people need to flag as VLQ for the system to take action? That sort of thing. (I haven't checked whether the question already exists, though)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I will do some more research and edit the body of the text. ...but a little later.

Comment: The stinkeroonie link doesn’t go anywhere

Comment: @DanBron Andrew Leach took it off the shelf. Gracias a Dios.

Comment: @Cascabel Aww, but I wanted to see it. Do you have a link lying around?

Comment: @DanBron    Nope. Cannot find it. Should've kept a copy because boy, believe you me, it sounded like a partially decoded cypher from some drug-addled alien living on Mars 9 in a total white-out of ammonia snow. In the world of VLQ queue,it is like the nadir of garbage.

Comment: I too would like to see this gem of s--t!

Comment: Guys...@AndrewLeach was the one to give this the heave-ho, at my request. Now that I think of it, possibly it was a first-offering from  some nascent Phillip K. Dick...

Comment: @sumelic That link is degraded. It only goes to the main.

Comment: The link goes to the answer; however, you won't be able to see it unless you have the privilege of viewing deleted answer posts.

Comment: @sumelic Ouch. Color me under-privileged. Is there any way we can make it available in some corner where we could look at this [lack of a better word] thing? Well, actually, it seems you guys do.

Comment: I just edited a screenshot into the question. If you find it too obtrusive, you can remove it again; it will be visible in the edit history of this post.

Answer (score 1):

If you flag a post as VLQ, the post is moved to the VLQ Review Queue.

Once a post is in the VLQ review queue, it is simply down to the reviewers.  Once the appropriate number (I believe it is six on ELU) click on *Recommend Deletion* within the review process, the post is deleted.  Or, of course, if the consensus is *Looks OK*, the post leaves the review queue and is kept.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/236563) on the Main Meta has more details.

The NAA (Not An Answer) flag also puts the post into the VLQ review queue but also raises a notification to the moderators.  In this case the moderators are more likely to see the post, and delete if necessary, but NAA requires different criteria to VLQ.